# Use value from PropsFromState in state constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this props interface:

```
interface OwnProps {
  onHide: () => void;
  show: boolean;
  onSubmit: (props: SetCompanyUploaderFormSchema) => void;
  client: Client;
}
```

And this PropsFromState interface:

```
interface PropsFromState {
  userList: DropDownListItem<string>[];
  userListIds: Array<number>;
}
```

Which I initialize like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: State, props: OwnProps): PropsFromState => ({
  userList: getCompanyTeamListSelector(state),
  userListIds: state.ddls.companyUsers.map(element => Number(element.id))
});
```

I am trying to set state value `selectedUsersIds` to `PropsFromState` value `userListIds`.

I tried to do this in the constructor:

```
@connect(mapStateToProps)
export default class EmailModal extends React.Component<OwnProps & Partial<PropsFromDispatch> & Partial<PropsFromState>, OwnState> {
  constructor(propsFromState: PropsFromState, props: OwnProps ) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedUserIds: propsFromState.userListIds
    }
  }
```

I tried `this.props.userListIds` as well.

In addition to that I tried to set it by using `getDerivedStateFromProps` and `ComponentWillMount`. Nothing worked so far and `this.state.selecteduserIds` is still comes up as empty array.

However, when I print `this.props.userListIds` at the beginning of the `render()` it shows up correctly.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

constructor(props:propsFromState) {}

And then call super(props);

Comment: It raises error: Argument of type 'PropsFromState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OwnProps & Partial<PropsFromDispatch> & Partial<PropsFromState>, OwnState>'. Should I change class declaration somehow?

Comment: Yes the constructor only receives props, and the constructor can set the initial state for that component. I see you are using redux which is great, but the power of redux is to avoid local state. In this scenario looking at the code, it’s not even necessary to set the state, you can just use the value from the received props. ( currently using my phone, I can supply some example code when I’m near my laptop )

Comment: SelecteduserIds is going to be dynamic value changing according to the checkboxes. At the beginning all the checkboxes needs to be checked ( all users selected). That's why I am getting all users from the State into the props.